# Uploaded File is becoming zero bytes if I use xmldocument.load to check for some validation and then uploading it to azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(file.InputStream);
                var x = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("typeId");
                if (x.Count == 0)
                {
                   getccdofuseranddoc(Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserID"]));
                    ViewBag.FileSizes = true;
                    return View();
                }
```

If i use this block of code the file becomes of zero when it is uploaded to azure blob , if this block of code is not used it works fine 
PS: this block is used to check the file only ; File s Content length is not zero at the time when Upload.Tostream is used.

Answer (score 1):

You may be overwriting the file somewhere else. Can you please provide the code showing how you upload to Blob storage?